# rounding error using the sum() function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL Fiddle of the issue I am having here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73964/1/0

My query is as follows:
select round(sum(qty*amount),2) as total from newtable;

I am expecting zero, but I am getting -0.01
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you expecting 0?

Comment: Try rounding multiplication, not the sum, so you get what you expect. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad9ce/1).

Answer (score 1):

The result of the calculation is `-0.005`

if you round that to 2 digits after the comma (what you are doing)  that makes it `-0.01` whichis correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    325   *    1    ->  325 
      0.5 *    9.63 ->    4.815
      1   * -129.24 -> -129.24
      1   * -200.58 -> -200.58
+   ---------------------------
                         -0.005

round(-0.005) -> -0.01
```

Comment: What I was expecting it to do ( and I was wrong to assume this) is for it to sum 0.5 *  9.63 and round that before adding them together. Wrong, I was!

Comment: you'd need `sum(round(...))` then. functions are applied innermost-first.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have been rounding the multiplication, not the sum.
Thanks everyone for pointing out my failure to comprehend :)

Correct query for what I was expecting is

```
select sum(round(qty*amount,2)) as total from newtable;
```